# Taking id from token so I can check if the user is the owner of the recource Passport Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am using passport for oauth authentication with token:

```
Route::middleware('auth:api') ->group (function(){
 //my routes
}
```

But in my update method I want to first check if the user that is authenticated is the owner of the recource. I am using Lcobucci\JWT\Parser to take the id of the user:

```
$value = $request->bearerToken();
$id = (new Parser())->parse($value)->getHeader('jti');
```

But I don't know where to put this code. The way in Spring I was taking the id in the middleware and storing it in the security context and then I could access it in my functions from the security context. How can I extend the auth:api middleware and it's guards so I store the id of my user?

Comment: Would it be the same for your code to directly retrieve the user instance? From it you could then get the user id. To do so: `$request->user()` would return the logged in user instance, `$request->user()->id` would fetch the id.

Comment: @mdexp yes thank you! I didn't know passport is getting the user for you. If you want make an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parsing token thing you were trying to do is done under the hood when you put the `auth:api` middleware in a route and call it by providing the bearer token.

If you dig into the source code the main "entry point" for the token check is in the `Authenticate` middleware that simply calls `Auth::check()`.
This, would trigger the check for an authenticated user on the authentication system that you are using (Passport in your case). It would parse the token and retrieve the authd user.

But when you use the `auth:api` middleware, you can always retrieve the logged in user instance in your controller without departing the token yourself.

To do so you have a couple of ways:

1. Through the `Auth` facade: `Auth::user()->id` or directly `Auth::id()`
2. Through the request instance: `$request->user()->id`.

**Note:** you can retrieve the request instance also with the `Request` facade, or with the `request()` helper method.

In any case the user method would give you the currently authenticated user instance. You can then fetch the id attribute.